# How to increment a column of a prisma table by one in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

It is possible on my javascript application to like posts. And I created an nb_likes column of integer type in the prisma table containing the different posts of the application. I would like when a like is added to a post, the value of the nb_likes column is incremented by 1. So I wrote the following code:

```
await db.post.update({
         . . .
          nb_likes : {
            increment,
          }
        },
      });
```

I expected the value of the nb_likes column to be implicitly increased by 1 but the `increment` keyword is not recognized. I searched the internet, but couldn't find anything about it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

With Prisma, you can perform atomic operations for Int and Float fields.

`increment: x:` Adds x to the current value

`decrement: x:` Subtracts x from the current value

`multiply: x:` Multiplies the current value by x

`divide: x:` Divides the current value by x

`set: x:` Sets the value to x (equivalent to data: { age: 18 })

You can learn more from the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#atomic-number-operations)

An example is shown

```js
const updatePosts = await prisma.post.updateMany({
  data: {
    views: {
      increment: 1,
    },
    likes: {
      increment: 1,
    },
  },
})
```